# why i am getting the following exception

Tags: java, alfresco

this is my nodefinder.java file

```
package com.acme.web.action.executer;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.Map;

import org.alfresco.web.bean.repository.Node;
import org.alfresco.web.bean.repository.Repository;
import org.alfresco.web.ui.common.component.UIActionLink;

import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

import org.alfresco.service.cmr.model.FileFolderService;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeService;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.StoreRef;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.search.SearchParameters;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.search.SearchService;

public class NodeFinder {

    // private static final String = null;
    SearchParameters sp = new SearchParameters();
    private NodeService nodeService;
    private FileFolderService fileFolderService;
    //geting the filefolder service                     
    public FileFolderService getFileFolderService() {
        return fileFolderService;
    }
    // setting the file folder service 
    public void setFileFolderService(FileFolderService fileFolderService) {
        this.fileFolderService = fileFolderService;
    }
// getting the node servise 
    public NodeService getNodeService() {
        return nodeService;
    }
    // setting the node server 

    public void setNodeService(NodeService nodeService) {
        this.nodeService = nodeService;
    }

    public void execute(ActionEvent event) {
        ResultSet resultSet_s = null;
        UIActionLink comp = (UIActionLink) event.getComponent();
        Map<String, String> params = comp.getParameterMap();
        String id = params.get("id1");
        System.out.println("1");

        NodeRef actionedUponNodeRef = new NodeRef(Repository.getStoreRef(), id);
        String qry_s = "@cm\\:name:train";
        System.out.println("2");

        SearchParameters sp_s = new SearchParameters();
        System.out.println("3");

        sp_s.addStore(StoreRef.STORE_REF_WORKSPACE_SPACESSTORE);
        sp_s.setLanguage(SearchService.LANGUAGE_LUCENE);

        sp_s.setQuery(qry_s);
        System.out.println( "4" );

        Node node = new Node(actionedUponNodeRef);
        System.out.println("5");
        resultSet_s = (ResultSet) Repository.getServiceRegistry(
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()).getSearchService().query(
                sp_s);
        System.out.println("5.1");

        if (resultSet_s != null) {
            System.out.println("6");

            System.out.println("Node value is::::" + node.getName());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting, and where's the exception?

Comment: i ahve created the gui component to get the node element of the content with node ref . but i am getting the followin error                   javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: Exception while invoking expression #{NodeFinder.execute}
caused by:
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.PagingLuceneResultSet cannot be cast to java.sql.ResultSet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at that line `...(ResultSet) Repository.getServiceRegistry(...`, then look at your exception and finally at your imports. There you will see that `ResultSet` is actually `java.sql.ResultSet` (which is indicated by your ClassCastException's message).

If you then look at the super classes or interfaces of `org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.PagingLuceneResultSet` I'd say you won't find any `java.sql.ResultSet`. That's why you get that exception.

Answer (score 5):

Because you imported `java.sql.ResultSet` instead of an alfresco class/interface compatible to `org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.PagingLuceneResultSet`

Comment: thaank u hage for giving the suggest . i ll try it out and come back